# Visual Studio: Exclude From Project Quickly

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have got thousands of files/folders inside a solution. For some reason I have to exclude them all and then include again in the project, to get the latest list of files.

The normal "Exclude From Project" in visual studio menu takes too much time. Is there a quick way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Curious to know why you need to exclude and then include the files back in the solution.  It's possible that there may be a technique that can make this redundant.

Comment: Sometimes, I update( & rename) image & few other files directly in the file system (outside visual studio). When I try to build & publish the project, lots files go missing and project can't be published. I thought doing a quick "exclude all" and then "include In project" would work.

Answer (score 0):

Put them all into one master folder and include that folder.

If some are files, you may also want to compile them and include the DLLs or the equivalent in whatever language you're using.